# What does the superscript x in Finnish IPA mean?

Tags: ipa, finnish, gemination

IPA transcriptions like `/muːtːuɑˣ/` from [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/muuttua) show a superscripted x. The [Finnish Phonology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finnish_phonology) Wiki page says, in the Sandhi section:

> Gemination of a morpheme-initial consonant occurs when the morpheme preceding it ends in a vowel and belongs to one of certain morphological classes. Gemination or a tendency of a morpheme to cause gemination is sometimes indicated with an apostrophe or a superscripted "x", e.g. vene /ʋeneˣ/. Examples of gemination:

I know that gemination is basically consonant lengthening, like when you say "ba**d** **d**ream". But that sentence is a little over my head and couldn't find much else. So does the "x" make a sound, or what is happening here? Can you explain it in slightly simpler terms? Why do so many Finnish words have it in the IPA transcription?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Phonemes are theoretical units, which don't always map directly to sounds.

In this case, to my understanding, the phonologist behind this analysis has proposed that there's a special phoneme `/ˣ/` which makes a following consonant geminate. For example, if *hake* "woodchips" is underlyingly `/ˈhɑkeˣ/`, that explains why *hake-lava* "woodchip-box" has a geminate `[hɑkelːɑʋɑ]`, while *lava* "box" doesn't: the gemination reflects underlying `/ˣl/`.

Some analyses of Japanese posit something similar, with a phoneme `/Q/` that lengthens a following consonant. In these analyses, `/Q/` and `/N/` are the only phonemes that can appear in a coda, and each get a mora of their own; a word like *Nippon* is phonemically something like `/niQ.poN/`.

Comment: Note, I know very little about Finnish. This is just my interpretation of what's written on Wikipedia, whether it's accurate or not.

Comment: I was going to supply the Japanese example in a comment, but I saw you had already covered it.  +1

Answer (score 3):

This is a well-known problem of Finnish phonology, made widely known to the general linguistic audience in [this article](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Ekiparsky/Keyser-Kiparsky_Finnish.pdf) by Keyser & Kiparsky. There is no standard notation for indicating this property in Finnish – K&K don't give this a segmental transcription, instead they treat it as being "CV". I have seen it treat as *h* also *k*, which is possible since there is no competing word *tervek* or *terveh* that has to be distinguished. It's a Wikipedia-internal issue as to why that non-standard notation is used, and you would have to ask the "author" why they use this notation. Outside of Wikipedia, we understand this to be a diacritic referring to the fact that there used to be some consonant there, which affects the contemporary phonology of the language. It is sometimes called a "fleeting" consonant.

In his historical treatment of the development of Finnish, Hakulinen (1961) speaks of this property as being a "laryngeal stop", written as ', which derives historically from *k*, *h*, *t* and *n*, and he also notes that

> In the pronunciation of modern Finnish the laryngeal stop is virtually
> non-existent. The mark ' used above and elsewhere in this book is a
> purely etymological sign with no phonetic value.